# Curl command to set permission and download file

Tags: linux, curl

How to use curl to download file and at same time to set the file permission. This for linux and permission of file will be '0775'

```
curl -u username:password -o 'directory/fileName.war' http://134.20.18.28:35000/fileName.war
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` does not do this, `chmod` does. Just `&&` your commands so if the first succeeds the second runs:

```
curl -u username:password -o 'directory/fileName.war' http://134.20.18.28:35000/fileName.war && chmod 0775 directory/fileName.war
```